# How to select specific date range repeating over multiple years in R?

Tags: r, date, select, filter, dplyr

Forgive me for probably not expressing myself with the proper terminology, as I am extremely new to R.

I am looking to isolate and keep 1)lockdown and 2)non-lockdown periods in my dataset for a pollution measurement station (called "Voiron Urbain") that I can then use to make basic plots. In other words, I want to keep the period of the first lockdown in France (ie, 2020/03/17 to 2020/05/11) for 2017, 2018, 2019, and 2020, 2020 being of course the wonderful year that would have its period of lockdown, and the other three eventually becoming "non-lockdown" used as reference years to compare pollution.

I have tried all sorts of variations suggested by answerers to similar questions, but the closest I got to anything that didn't give me an error I didn't know how to fix is the following :
`data_pm10_4stations" being my initial dataset, and 'conf' standing for 'confinement' (French)

```
data_pm10_4stations_conf <- data.frame(begin=seq(as.Date('2017/03/17'), 
                                   length.out=4, by="years"),
                         end=seq(as.Date('2017/05/11'),
                                 length.out=4, by="years"))
```

However, somewhat expectedly but still disappointingly, all I get is this new dataframe, and I don't know how to merge with my old table or how to get it to show with my Voiron Urbain column :

```
  begin      end
1 2017-03-17 2017-05-11
2 2018-03-17 2018-05-11
3 2019-03-17 2019-05-11
4 2020-03-17 2020-05-11
```

My professor suggests the following below for the same exercise (but different dataset) which makes almost total sense. In her dataset, she has columns for Years (Annee), Months (Mois), and Days (Jour), but I'm not sure why she has those columns, nor how to apply her code with a simple "date" column (which is already specified to R as dates, by the way, so I know that's not the issue).
I still get errors when I try applying it to my dataset quite simply because I have no idea what I'm doing. Here is her code :

```
PM_IDF_jour_conf <- PM_IDF_jour_SansNA %>% 
  mutate(JourConfin=if_else(((Mois==5 & Jour <= 11) | (Mois == 3 & Jour>=17) | Mois==4) , 1, 0)) %>% 
  filter(JourConfin==1) %>% 
  select(date, Annee, Jour, Mois, A1, BOB, RUR_S)
```

This is what I tried which obviously didn't work. Don't know why I had even a glimmer of hope *eyeroll*

```
data_pm10_4stations_conf <- data_pm10_4stations %>% 
  mutate[JourConfin=if_else("2017/03/17":"2017/05/11", 1, 0) %>% 
           filter(JourConfin==1) %>% 
           select(date, 'Voiron Urbain')]
```

As per suggestions from other post threads, I tried these, but I fear they will not be very helpful to me because I won't know what to do with the result, just like the first line of code I wrote in this post.

```
start_date <- as.Date("2017/03/17")
end_date <- as.Date("2017/05/11")
seq(start_date, by = "day", length.out = 4)
```

```
data_pm10_4stations_conf <- seq.Date("2017/03/17", "2017/05/11", by = "days")
```

```
data_pm10_4stations_conf <- seq(as.Date("2017/03/17"),as.Date("2017/05/11"),by = 'day')
```

```
data_pm10_4stations_conf <- data_pm10_4stations %>% 
  select(Voiron Urbain, cdate) %>%
  filter( cdate>=as.Date("2017/03/17") & cdate<=as.Date("2017/05/11") )
data_pm10_4stations_conf
```

```
data_pm10_4stations_conf <- data.frame(begin=seq(as.Date('2017/03/17'), 
                                   length.out=4, by="years"),
                         end=seq(as.Date('2017/05/11'),
                                 length.out=4, by="years"))
```

I think my professor's suggestion with `mutate` `filter` `select` will give me what I need most efficiently, I just need help to fix what I did wrong when applying it to my situation. So focus your thinking power on that one in particular pretty please!

Thank you so much for your help and kindness and for explaining things as though I don't know anything (because I really don't and am forced to endure R against my own will).

Comment: Hi Marian! Welcome. Sounds like a frustrating problem! Unfortunately, it's quite hard to see what your desired output is. Is it possible for you to shorten the question with a simpler example so that we can help?

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to give an answer without your data. But, if I understood correctly, it's similar to something I had to go through few weeks ago.

Basically, you want to divide your original dataset in two. A "lockdown" and a "non-lockdown" one according to a time interval, or multiple time intervals.

You could try by using the `lubridate` package.

```
#install and load lubridate
install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

#This is to create a df with every day for the 2017-2020 time span
years <- data.frame(days = seq(as.Date('2017/01/01'), length.out = 1461, by = "days"))

#Create a lockdown interval for every year
i_17 <- interval(ymd("2017/3/17"), ymd("2017/5/11")) 
i_18 <- interval(ymd("2018/3/17"), ymd("2018/5/11")) 
i_19 <- interval(ymd("2019/3/17"), ymd("2019/5/11")) 
i_20 <- interval(ymd("2020/3/17"), ymd("2020/5/11")) 

#Create a new column 'conf' that you can use to filter lockdown and non-lockdown data
conf_periods <- years %>% 
  mutate(conf = if_else(days %within% list(i_17,i_18,i_19,i_20), TRUE, FALSE))


lockdown <- conf_periods %>% filter(conf == TRUE)

non_lockdown <- conf_periods %>% filter(conf == FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

My professor finally responded with this, saying my error was in my date format (in my dataset, it's y-m-d, not y/m/d). Stupid mistake, but her answer still isn't helpful for the next step.

```
data_pm10_4stations_conf <- data_pm10_4stations %>%
  mutate(JourConfin=if_else(date %in% as.Date("2017-03-17"):as.Date("2017-05-11"), 1, 0)) %>%
  filter(JourConfin==1) %>%
  select(date, "Voiron Urbain")
```

I applied her answer to each year and merged the four tables, since I didn't know a better way to do it.

```
#### 2.3. Define lockdown period
# For 2017
data_pm10_4stations_conf <- data_pm10_4stations %>% # creer un nouveau tableau pour la periode confinement 2017
  mutate(JourConfin=if_else(date %in% as.Date("2017-03-17"):as.Date("2017-05-11"), 1, 0)) %>% # ajouter nouvelles variables en conservant anciennes
  filter(JourConfin==1) %>%
  select(date, "Voiron Urbain")

# For 2018
data_pm10_4stations_conf18 <- data_pm10_4stations %>% # creer un nouveau tableau pour la periode confinement 2018
  mutate(JourConfin=if_else(date %in% as.Date("2018-03-17"):as.Date("2018-05-11"), 1, 0)) %>% 
  filter(JourConfin==1) %>%
  select(date, "Voiron Urbain")

# For 2019
data_pm10_4stations_conf19 <- data_pm10_4stations %>% # creer un nouveau tableau pour la periode confinement 2019
  mutate(JourConfin=if_else(date %in% as.Date("2019-03-17"):as.Date("2019-05-11"), 1, 0)) %>% 
  filter(JourConfin==1) %>%
  select(date, "Voiron Urbain")

# For 2020
data_pm10_4stations_conf20 <- data_pm10_4stations %>% # creer un nouveau tableau pour la periode confinement 2020
  mutate(JourConfin=if_else(date %in% as.Date("2020-03-17"):as.Date("2020-05-11"), 1, 0)) %>% 
  filter(JourConfin==1) %>%
  select(date, "Voiron Urbain")

# Join tables of lockdown periods for years 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020
data_pm10_4stations_conf_total <- rbind(data_pm10_4stations_conf, data_pm10_4stations_conf18, data_pm10_4stations_conf19, data_pm10_4stations_conf20)
```

I think I'll go with what you did @ornaldo because her answer only got me slightly further... Now I'm stuck again trying to `mutate` with `if_else` to add a "Lockdown" column to my new df (which in theory would categorize my lockdown/non-lockdown periods), but handling dates is really messing me up. I don't understand how to work with them. I had already installed the `lubridate` package and thought I was using it, but again, I don't understand most of what I'm doing, so...

Thanks so much for your help! It is quite incredible.